# Prove $ | \int_{\nu}^{\delta} \frac{\sin{((2N+1)\pi t)}}{\pi t} \,dt | \leq 2 \sup \limits_{M > 0} | \int_{0}^{M} \frac{\sin{\pi t}}{t} \,dt |$.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of Jordan's criterion for the convergence of the Fourier series of a function $f \in L^{1}(\Bbb T)$.  At the end of the proof, the following inequalities are used, and I have no idea how to prove they hold.

If $0 < \nu < \delta < \frac{1}{2}$, then:

$\left  | \int_{\nu}^{\delta} \frac{\sin{((2N+1)\pi t)}}{\pi t} \,dt \right | \leq 2 \sup \limits_{M > 0} \left | \int_{0}^{M} \frac{\sin{\pi t}}{t} \,dt  \right | < C$ for some constant $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int_{\nu}^{\delta}\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi t)}{\pi t}\,dt = \int_{(2N+1)\nu}^{(2N+1)\delta}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\,dt\\=\int_{0}^{(2N+1)\delta}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\,dt-\int_{0}^{(2N+1)\nu}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\,dt$$
so, by considering absolute values,
$$ |I|\leq 2\cdot\sup_{M\in\mathbb{R}^+}\left|\int_{0}^{M}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\,dt\right|.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi t)$ is a continuous function in a right neighbourhood of the origin, $\sin(\pi t)$ is a function with a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{\pi t}$ is a continuous and decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, so the RHS of $(1)$ is finite due to the (continuous version of) Dirichlet's test.

Comment: What is bounded primitive?  Also, you have a typo after "On the other hand".

Comment: A primitive that is a bounded function is a bounded primitive. Moreover, no typo, $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Oh ok, a bounded primitive is a primitive that is bounded.... What is a primitive?

Comment: An antiderivative! How do you call $\int f(x)\,dx$ ?

Comment: Oh I see.  I haven't heard it called a primitive before.  Also, is sinc standard notation?  I've never seen that notation used.

Comment: I may have accepted this answer (and it is a good one), but I'm not happy that you abandoned the comments.  I had more questions.  I just wanted to let you know that.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variable: $t \to (2N+1)t$,

$\displaystyle \int_{\nu}^{\delta} \frac{\sin{((2N+1)\pi t)}}{\pi t} \,dt = \int_{(2N+1)\nu}^{(2N+1)\delta} \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t} \,dt \le \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{(2N+1)\max\{|\delta|,|\nu|\}} \frac{\sin \pi t}{t} \,dt$

Comment: I think you are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2N + 1}$ outside of your second integral.

Comment: @user46944 why should there be a $\frac{1}{2N+1}$ outside?

Comment: If $u = (2N + 1)t$ then $du = (2N + 1)dt$ and so $\frac{1}{2N + 1} du = dt$.

Comment: Oh I think it cancels out with the factor you get from the $\pi t$ in the denominator.

Comment: @user46944 yes!

Comment: So, where do I go with the last integral?  That integral is bounded from above by $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{(2N + 1)\max\{ |\delta|, |\nu| \}} \frac{1}{t} \,dt$, but I can't see where to go from there.