# Show that $\sup_{0<c<\delta<\frac{1}{2}}\left|\int_{c}^{\delta}\frac{\sin \pi(2n+1)t}{\sin\pi t}dt\right|<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

As I was trying to understand the proof of Jordan's theorem, I'm trying to show that $$\sup_{0<c<\delta<\frac{1}{2}}\left|\int_{c}^{\delta}\frac{\sin \pi(2n+1)t}{\sin\pi t}dt\right|<\infty$$

I found a similar question on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106982/prove-int-nu-delta-frac-sin2n1-pi-t-pi-t-dt-leq-2-s), but since the denominator has another $\sin \pi t$, changing the bounds would not do the trick. I tried to break it down to two different functions so I can use integration by parts, but that didn't really get me anywhere. I think I do have to use the fact that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: If $c$ and $\delta$ are both bounded away from $0$ (say in relation to $n$), then you can bound the denominator away from $0$ which helps. Otherwise, a hint would be to use the fact that $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigonometric identity to show

$$
\frac{\sin\pi(2n+1)t}{\sin\pi t}=1+2\sum_{m=1}^n\cos2m\pi t
$$

This identity is one of the [Lagrange's trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities) and this function is called the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$
\left|\int_{c}^{\delta}\frac{\sin \pi(2n+1)t}{\sin\pi t}dt-\int_{c}^{\delta}\frac{\sin \pi(2n+1)t}{\pi t}dt
\right|
$$
and note that for $0<x<\pi/2$,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\right|\le cx
$$
where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more? Why is it necessary to take the difference and how is the second line relevant?